# PagSeguro .Net Core Problema com .xml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou implementando o pagamento com PagSeguro, porem estou tendo problema na execução da seguinte linha:

```
const bool isSandbox = true;
EnvironmentConfiguration.ChangeEnvironment(isSandbox);
```

Ao fazer algumas pesquisas descobri que não tinha adicionado a pasta com *.xml*
chamada *Configuration/PagSeguroConfig.xml* então incluí eles no projeto principal.  Porém ainda estou recebendo a mensagem que não foi possível encontrar o xml.

Acho q é necessário fazer uma validação do caminho de leitura localizado em *Uol.PagSeguro/Resources/PagSeguroConfiguration.cs*, onde logo no inicio tenho:

```
private static string urlXmlConfiguration = ".../.../Configuration/PagSeguroConfig.xml";
```

Em alguns foram encontrei que este era necessário alterar de modo que fosse direcionado para a raiz do projeto deixando assim:

```
private static string urlXmlConfiguration = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "PagSeguroConfig.xml";
```

Mas não estou conseguindo usar o HttpRuntime dentro do projeto .aspnet Core Standard. Como posso estar contornando este problema?

Comment: Eluander na documentação da PagSeguro é especificado onde o caminho deve ficar?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti, Segundo a documentação pode ficar em caminho de minha preferência, porém não estou conseguindo fazer esse caminho ser encontrado no core... https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/documentacao-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-netframework.html#PagSeguroConfiguration

Comment: Consegue fazer isso? private static string urlXmlConfiguration = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "PagSeguroConfig.xml");

Comment: @Rafael Tentei usar este que me passou, porem não acha referencia para o AppContext

Comment: Olha, acho que não tem suporte para o .NET Core, porém uma pessoa realizou um pull request a tempos com esse suporte: https://github.com/pagseguro/pagseguro-sdk-dotnet/pull/18/files#, se for o caso talvez se vc "embedar" o xml dentro do assembly e modificar o código que carregar dentro dessa classe, talvez resolva partialmente, vou tentar baixar o sdk e fazer um teste aqui mais tarde.

Comment: @Rafael Consegui descobrir porque não havia referencia para o AppContext, era poque a biblioteca que importei estava no 4.5 sendo que o restante esta em .core 2.1. Modifiquei a biblioteca de classes para o core então foi encontrado o AppContext... após fazer alguns testes. A Url  que agora está retornando é "C:\\Users\\Eluander\\Documents\\Developer\\PagSupera\\src\\Pag.Core.Api\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\PagSeguroConfig.xml" e assim continua o erro com o xml...

Comment: Navega nessa pasta e procura onde ele está e corrige o Path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um projeto ASP.NET Core e adicionei o projeto da UOL.PagSeguro, fiz a seguintes modificações:

No projeto da UOL.PagSeguro modifiquei o `urlXmlConfiguration` para:

```
 private static string urlXmlConfiguration = "Config/PagSeguroConfig.xml";
```

No projeto ASP.NET Core adicionei a pasta Config e dentro dela o `PagSeguroConfig.xml`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Modifiquei a propriedade *copy to output Directory/Copiar para Diretório de saída* do arquivo .xml para que ele seja copiado junto da pasta do assembly quando o mesmo for publicado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz uma action que carrega e retorna os dados das credenciais e coloquei um link no menu para testar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionei o código fonte no GITHUB:

https://github.com/superrfm/aspnetcorepagseguro

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou 100%! Obrigado por compartilhar!

Comment: Este projeto `Uol.PagSeguro` https://github.com/superrfm/aspnetcorepagseguro/tree/master/Uol.PagSeguro é alguma cópia da lib do PagSerguro ou o que?